# C# Dynamic indexer

Tags: c#

Does anybody know if it's possible to call method on CLR object via indexer using dynamic lang features? For instance,  `myClrObj["SuperMethod"] ()`  which I can easily do in javascript.

thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways, but one way I'd know how to do it is:

- Create a class that inherits from `DynamicObject`
- override the suitable method to capture the access via indexer
- Construct and cache a delegate that corresponds to the method that you find via the provided indexer argument
- Provide an extension method that suitably makes your object appear dynamic, with the correct DynamicObject specialization instantiated.

  `dynamic obj = myObj.AsIndexedObj(); obj["Do"]();`

Comment: Great idea, but it's not fit. I have existing classes that is not dynamic derived.

Comment: You don't have to derive your objects from the DynamicObject. Instead, create something of an adapter that interacts dynamically on behalf of your original object. This has the advantage that it becomes reusable throughout many types of object

Answer (score 0):

You could use the opensource [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) available via nuget, it wraps the DLR API to make it simpler to dynamically call a method by name, works for both dynamic and poco objects. Faster than reflection for poco objects.

```
Dynamic.InvokeMember(myClrObj,"SuperMethod")
```